# How to keep the first occurrence of a variable in a loop(Baby Step Giant Step algorithm)

Tags: java

I am implementing the Baby Step Giant Step algorithm. For this I need to solve 2 rows.
y,ay,a^2 y,…,a^(m-1) y (mod p)
a^m,a^2m,…,a^km  (mod p)

I write the whole series to a variable in the first loop, in the second loop I have to find the first value from the first loop and save it to the variable and finish the work of the second loop.
I did not succeed in the last action, to find the first matching number from the first cycle in the second and save the index of this number.
How can i do this?

```
for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(m) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    BigInteger temp = y.multiply(a.pow(i.intValue())).mod(p);
    System.out.println(temp);
    map1.put(i, temp);
}

for(BigInteger j = BigInteger.ONE; j.compareTo(k.multiply(m)) < 0; j = j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    BigInteger temp = a.pow(j.multiply(m).intValue()).mod(p);
    //System.out.println("temp = " + temp);
    /*if(map1.get(j).equals(temp)) {
        index = j;
        break;
    }*/
    for (var entry : map1.entrySet()) {
        if(Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), temp)) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, the *break* inside the nested loop only breaks you out of that nested loop. It doesn't get you out of the second loop as a whole.

What you can do as an alternative is convert the second for into a function, and return instead of break.

```java
private BigInteger findIndexInMap(TypeOfMap map1) {

    for(BigInteger j = BigInteger.ONE; j.compareTo(k.multiply(m)) < 0; j = j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        BigInteger temp = a.pow(j.multiply(m).intValue()).mod(p);
        for (var entry : map1.entrySet()) {
            if(Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), temp)) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                return entry.getKey()
            }
        }
    }

}
```